# Can the Law of supply and demand be derived from the Subjective Theory of Value using Agent-based modeling?

Tags: supply-and-demand, nonexpert

I was tinking about the Law of Supply and Demand and Subjective Theory of Value and I have the intuition that the first can be derived from the second using agent-based modeling. Is this true?

Also I am wondering if the converse is also true?